# How to find all select queries from a storedprocedure script in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I have a list of procedures in my SQL server , and I want to replace all select * statement with select (all column names) of that table. To do that , I need to identify all the select statements of the proceudure script. Here is my current code.

```
  foreach (StoredProcedure myproc in SelectedProcedures)
                {


                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    ScriptingOptions scriptOptions = new ScriptingOptions();
                    StringCollection tableScripts = myproc.Script();
                    foreach (string script in tableScripts)
                    {
                        if (script.ToUpper().Contains("CREATE PROCEDURE"))
                        {
                          string x = script.ToUpper().Replace("CREATE PROCEDURE", "ALTER PROCEDURE");
                            builder.Append(x + "\n");
                            if (script.ToString().ToUpper().Replace("  ", " ").Contains("SELECT * FROM "))
                            {
                                string u = script.ToString().ToUpper().Replace("  ", " ");
                                List<string> values = u.Split(new string[] { "SELECT * FROM " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
                                List<string> tablenames = new List<string>();
                                values.RemoveAt(0);
                                foreach (string t in values)
                                {
                                    if (!t.Trim().StartsWith("#") && !t.Trim().StartsWith("@"))
                                    {
                                        tablenames.Add(t.Split(' ')[0].Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").ToUpper().Trim());
                                    }
                                }
                                tablenames.OrderBy(xx => xx);
                                List<Table> tables = SourceDB.Tables.Cast<Table>().Where(t => tablenames.Contains(t.ToString().Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").ToUpper())).Select(t => t).ToList();

                                foreach (var t in tablenames)
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        Table mytable = SourceDB.Tables[t.Split('.')[1], t.Split('.')[0]];
                                        if (mytable != null)
                                        {
                                            StringBuilder builder1 = new StringBuilder();
                                            builder1.Append("SELECT ");

                                            foreach (Column column in mytable.Columns)
                                            {
                                                builder1.Append("[" + column.Name.ToUpper() + "], ");
                                            }
                                            builder1.Remove(builder1.ToString().LastIndexOf(", "), 1);
                                            builder1.Append(" from ");
                                            builder1.Append(mytable.ToString());
                                            GeneratedScripts["Procedures"].Add(builder1);
                                            string k = builder.ToString().ToUpper();
                                            string n = k.Replace("  ", " ").Replace("SELECT * FROM " + mytable.ToString().ToUpper(), builder1.ToString());
                                            n = n.Replace("  ", " ").Replace("SELECT * FROM " + t, builder1.ToString());
                                            builder = new StringBuilder(n);

                                        }
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception)
                                    {

                                        continue;
                                    }



                                }

                            }
                        }



                    }
```

However this omits cases like select B.* from table A inner join table B
I can use additional logic , like Regex , to handle this things , but I want a more appropriate way so that I retrieve all select queries of a procedure script in a list of string , and then i can use my custom logic over all the queries one by one.

Thanks

Comment: In order to do this properly you will have to write a complete SQL parser - not an easy thing to do. You might want to look at commercial products that do this sort of thing.

Comment: There is an existing free Api, have a look at DacFx and TSqlObject that will give you statements from a stored procedure. It is the api that is used by ssdt that qxg shows in his answer ( if you do write it please Oss it as it would be useful for others).

Comment: It is actually ScriptDom not TSqlObjects, this shows how to get statements but you can also get the columns and tables etc: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arvindsh/archive/2013/04/04/using-the-transactsql-scriptdom-parser-to-get-statement-counts.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's easy if your database is developed by SSDT, which is included by default after Visual Studio 2013. In SSDT, just right click project node, and select Refactor -> Expand Wildcards. SSDT internally build a model of database schema, so it's very smart to figure accurate columns.

With this tool (I believe other tools), you still need to pay attention to query like `EXISTS (SELECT * FROM` OR `SELECT COUNT(*)`. Replacing them doesn't make much sense.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I'd do this with some assumptions:

Look for a regex match where a * occurs between a SELECT and a FROM.
Only possible exclusion would be if the SELECT is immediately preceded by an 'EXISTS(' which may or may not contain spaces or tabs.

Other alternatives would be to just keep an eye on the execution plan cache and look for your most used queries.

Another great (or better) alternative is to start doing code analysis which could contain rules for this.